# PHP can't get json from local page, only remote url

Tags: php, json, slim, slim-3

I'm currently building a site using the Slim framework. I have an endpoint setup on my site and it is working but when trying to get it using PHP `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()` nothing is returned. When I run the same code but change out the url to a remote public API, the json is decoded and output to the page.

Working Code

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$results = json_decode($contents); // Returns JSON array
```

Does not work with local site

```
$url = "https://local/api/endpoint";
$contents = file_get_contents($url); 
$results = json_decode($contents); // Returns NULL
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Possibly headers?

Comment: When you put - https://local/api/endpoint into your browser - what do you see?

Comment: `local/api/endpoint` gives me a 404 but if I route it through HTTPS it gives me the expected json. Could the https have something to do with it because PHP is just sending http instead?

Comment: The HTTPS got dropped off the text for the url in my question. In answer to your question, yes, that would be something to check?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Doesn't make sense since when I define the URL it is going through HTTPS.

Comment: Well yes... According to your code in your question you are using HTTPS. What else do you have going on that's different?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw There really isn't anything that I could think of that should cause this. The endpoint is giving out valid json headers and since it's on the same url, it shouldn't be anything cross origin related.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157210/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-joe-scotto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local endpoint is failing because php is unable to verify the SSL certificate, in the case you are using a self signed certificate. In local development you can circumvent SSL CA checking by modifying the default stream context:

```
$stream_opts = [
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ]
];  
$response = file_get_contents("https://local/api/endpoint",
           false, stream_context_create($stream_opts));
```